# Placing to table div and inline-block div next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to place two divs next to each other. The first of them is displayed as a table and other one is an inline div. Here is some code: http://jsfiddle.net/WcHEc/

And also inline code.

HTML:

```
<div class="message-container">
    <div class="img-rounded small">
        <div class="img-centered-wrapper">
            <img src="/static/img/avatar" class="img-animal" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-content">
        <p><strong>Some title</strong></p>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message-container {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
}
.message-container .right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.img-rounded {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-centered-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.message-content {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.img-animal {
    max-height: 45px;
    max-width: 45px;
}
```

I'd like div "message-content" to be always displayed on the right of a div "img-rounded". But when there is too much content in "message-content" then it's displayed below. I'm struggling with it for some time and have no idea how to make it work.
I'd very glad for any help.

**Edit**

Thank you for you answers! It helped me to figure out what was the problem.

I didn't set width and height, because my idea was that `.message-container` will fit to its content, because I'm using border on it.

So instead of setting `inline` and fixed width, I keep displaying it as an `inline-block` and also I set `max-width` to `.message-content`. Here is a little bit bigger piece of code: http://jsfiddle.net/RpZcT/.

Do you have any idea how to achive the same effect with using `inline` instead of `inline-block`? As it was mentioned, `inline-block` may cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you have not set `width` and `height` to the `divs`?

Comment: yes, I just edited my post. I'd like message-container to fit to it's content. I should've mentioned it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set `.message-container` to act as a wrapper. This will save you some headache later on. Set both of the `divs` to `float:left;`. This will keep them aligned as well.

```
.message-container {
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Note** 
1) It is a good idea to specify `width` on the `divs`, otherwise `width` will be auto or inherited, which can be problematic. 
2) The use of `display: inline-block;` within some browsers can cause unexpected behaviour, so I would use `display: inline;` only.

Have a look at the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tob1as/WcHEc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of `.message content`:

```
.message-content {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

So it will be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/WcHEc/1/